# How to find the square root of a big integer in R language? (package gmp doesn't have sqrt for bigz)

Tags: r, algorithm, biginteger, bigint, square-root

I'm trying to find the square root of a big integer in R language. I'm using package gmp which provides bigz for big integers but it seems it's missing a function for square root. I'm opened to using another package for big integers if needed.

```
library(gmp)
 sqrt(as.bigz("113423713055421844361000443349850346743"))
Error: 'Math.bigz' is not implemented yet
```

Alternatively I'm looking for a way to implement sqrt using bigz.

Comment: Rich, sorry, I should have used a larger number to avoid confusion. I edited my question to reflect that. Yes, sqrt works for numbers that can be expressed in a standard way by R but I'm looking for doing the same with larger numbers (which is why I used gmp/bigz).

Comment: Joseph, thanks, it seems it's working! It seems I can't just do a as.bigz(sqrt(a)) so I'll still need to do a bit more research. Or I'll have to see if using mpfr instead of bigz has a significant impact on performance.

Comment: just an FYI... 1. `Rmpfr` in an extension of `gmp`;  2. `Rmpfr` is designed specifically for floating point calculations whereas `gmp` is aimed at integers and rationals. My point is that they are designed for a very specific and very different tasks, so it isn't a matter of which library is more powerful for calculating the `sqrt` (or any arithmetic operation that could possibly result in irrational numbers.. e.g. `log`), it's more of, you must use `Rmpfr` in order to achieve your desired outcome.

Comment: Thanks, I looked up the documentation and found .mpfr2bigz(sqrt(a)) converts it back into bigz. I had meantime fun thinking up an algorithm to find sqrt but I haven't implemented it yet and your solution plus .mpfr2bigz does what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of problem is exactly what the [Rmpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/Rmpfr.pdf) package was built for.

```
library(Rmpfr)
a <- mpfr("113423713055421844361000443349850346743", 128)  ## specify the number of bits
sqrt(a)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 
[1] 10650056950806500000.00000005163589039117
```

It should be noted that in order to access the power of this package, you must first declare your variable as an `mpfr` object. Once you have done this, you can easily perform any number of arithmetic operations to any number of precision of bits (up to memory).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might want to use logs to do calculations with big numbers. I.e. x^y = exp(y*log(x)).

```
library(gmp)
x <- 113423713055421844361000443349850346743
as.bigz(exp(0.5*log(as.bigz(x))))
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 10650056950806493184
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I had tried x^0.5 but it didn't work. I see the idea behind your answer works even though the exact example you gave doesn't work: if you multiply your result by itself it will give a different number than the original number (I got 113423713055421699179424088855838457856, compare the last digits). To fix this you need to use quotes: x <- '113423713055421844361000443349850346743'. Else, due to being a larger number than what R can handle, R will not store it and subsequently pass it properly to the as.bigz() function.